# Finding data by inputing a name associated to the data

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm developing a simple stats program for runners here.  It takes the data for one race only. I have the code for the first part running after some help from stackoverflow!
The idea is that after a race we can input the runner's name and their time.  I'm hoping then to search for a person's run time by searching for their name (then you would see the runner's name and their time displayed to screen.  Is it possible to do this in Java?? Thanks Cassy.

Here is my code...

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Trying
{

public static void main (String[] args)

    {
    int num;

    Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("******************************************************************* ");
    System.out.println("Welcome to Running Race Time Statistical Analysis Application");
    System.out.println("******************************************************************* \n");


    System.out.println("Please input number of participants (2 to 10)");

    num=input.nextInt();

    // If the user enters an invalid number... display error message...
    while(num<2|| num >10)
    {
        System.out.println("Error invalid input! Try again! \nPlease input a valid number of participants (2-10)...");

        num=input.nextInt();
    }

    // declare arrays
    double resultArray [] = new double [num]; // create result array with new operator
    String nameArray [] = new String [num];// create name array with new operator
    // Using the num int will ensure that the array holds the number of elements inputed by user


    // loop to take in user input for both arrays (name and result)
    double count = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nameArray.length ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println ("Please enter a race participant Name for runner " + (i+1) );
            nameArray[i] = input.next();

            System.out.println ("Please enter a race result (time between 0.00 and 10.00) for runner " + (i+1) );
            resultArray[i] = input.nextDouble();

            count += resultArray[i]; // This count variable is used later to calculate average from total
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and your code looks broadly workable. Note, however, that this "parallel arrays" design is a strong indicator that you should instead have a class `Runner` with fields `name` and `result`, and an array (or better yet, `List`) of `Runner` objects.

Comment: Its essemtially a search by name function that I'm hoping to implement

Comment: Thanks chrylis but I'm not sure how to do that!

Comment: Just developing my Java skills here! They're pretty basic at present but hoping to learn quickly!

Comment: The simplest approach here would be to store the names and times in a `HashMap`, instead of a pair of arrays.  I strongly recommend reading up on `HashMap`, because this kind of problem comes up over and over, and the use of `HashMap` is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the user to be able to search for a name, then use this:

```
String entered;
while(true) {
    entered = input.nextLine();
    if(entered.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;
    for(int i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
        if(entered.equals(nameArray[i])) {
            System.out.println("Name: " + nameArray[i] + "\tTime: " + resultArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to implement a lookup is with a `HashMap` or some other kind of `Map`.  It will also perform more efficiently than a pair of arrays.  The trick is to store all your names and times in the `HashMap`, with code something like this.

```
Map<String, Double> raceTimes = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= participants; i++) {
    // ... some code here to enter the name and the time

    raceTimes.put(name, time);
}
```

It's then easy to retrieve a time from the `HashMap`, if you have the name.  The code would look like this.

```
Double time = raceTimes.get(nameEntered);
if (time != null) {
    System.out.println(nameEntered + " has a time of " + time);
}
```

The null check is there in case the user enters a name that doesn't correspond to one of the participants.  The actual lookup is just the one expression `raceTimes.get(nameEntered)` - this is FAR simpler than using two arrays, and looping through looking for the value that you want.

I took the liberty of tying all of this together into a complete solution for you.  You can see that I've also changed a couple of other things.

- I've broken this down into separate methods, because `main` was getting unmanageably long.
- I've changed the prompt for the participant's name, to use `nextLine`, since `next` will only read a single word.  This will let participants have names consisting of several words.  But along with this change, I had to add an extra call to `nextLine` after calls to `nextInt` and `nextDouble`, because a call to `nextInt` or `nextDouble` doesn't read the newline character after the number - so you need an additional `nextLine` to read the newline.

My entire code is as follows.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RaceTimes{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("******************************************************************* ");
        System.out.println("Welcome to Running Race Time Statistical Analysis Application");
        System.out.println("******************************************************************* \n");

        int participants = enterNumberOfParticipants(input);
        Map<String, Double> raceTimes = enterTimes(input, participants);
        lookupTimes(input, raceTimes);
        input.close();
    }

    private static int enterNumberOfParticipants(Scanner input) {
        System.out.println("Please input number of participants (2 to 10)");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        while (num < 2 || num > 10) {
            System.out.println("Error invalid input! Try again! \nPlease input a valid number of participants (2-10)...");
            num = input.nextInt();
        }
        input.nextLine();
        return num;
    }

    private static Map<String, Double> enterTimes(Scanner input, int participants) {
        Map<String, Double> raceTimes = new HashMap<>();

        // loop to take in user input for both arrays (name and result)
        double totalTime = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= participants; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a race participant Name for runner " + i);
            String name = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter a race result (time between 0.00 and 10.00) for runner " + i);
            Double time = input.nextDouble();
            input.nextLine();
            totalTime += time;

            raceTimes.put(name, time);
        }
        System.out.println("Average time is " + totalTime / participants);
        return raceTimes;
    }

    private static void lookupTimes(Scanner input, Map<String, Double> raceTimes) {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a name that you'd like to know the time for, or type quit.");
            String nameEntered = input.nextLine();
            if(nameEntered.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                return;
            }
            Double time = raceTimes.get(nameEntered);
            if (time != null) {
                System.out.println(nameEntered + " has a time of " + time);
            } else {
                System.out.println("There is no participant called " + nameEntered);
            }
        }
    }
}
```